# Ms access file with with persian and english text

Tags: ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access database file with the .mdb extention. It's database of a flashcard program and it contains English and Persian text.

When I open it with Access there is no English or Persian text, instead it shows some strange characters that make no sense. I just want to extract plain text of the file.

[image]

Comment: you don't have the right font to display the text, or access is mangling the text, not knowing what encoding its in.

Comment: This is not a programming question.  For help with general purpose software, you should ask the question on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).